# on iOS with mapkit "multible" how do display markers

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, google-maps-markers, gesture, tap

Getting a single marker was easy, trying to click on main points an leave behind a marker seems easy but I am getting a weird error. Anybody been down this path?

Define array for markers

```swift
@State private var markers: [MarkerData] = []
```

Inside Mapview class

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack(){
        
        GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
            MapReader { mapProxy in
                Map(position: $cameraPosition, interactionModes: modes) {
                    if let markerData {
                        Marker("Spot", coordinate: markerData.coordinate)
                    }
// This does not work.
// error: Type '()' cannot conform to 'MapContent'
                    markers.forEach { marker in
                        print(marker.coordinate)
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture { screenCoordinate in
                    self.markerData = mapProxy.markerData(screenCoordinate: screenCoordinate, geometryProxy: geometryProxy)
                    
                    if let markerData = self.markerData{
                        markers.append(markerData)
                    }
                }
```

The line “//error” shows the error I'm getting
and the on `onTapGesture` shows how I add them to the list

The sample source code can be found on GitHub
https://github.com/tomha2014/LearnMapKitiOS17

Comment: Put that code in an onAppear

Comment: You **cannot** have "normal" code like `markers.forEach ...` in the closure of the `Map`.
You can only have what is permitted, such as `Marker`, `Annotations` etc... not procedural code that does not 
return one of those map elements.
See: [Map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map)
You probably wanted to use `ForEach(markers) { marker in      Marker("xxx", .....) }`

Comment: Agreed. Also I am not sure what you meant by “multible”? Mutable? Multiple?

Comment: thank you, for your advice. The ForEach(marker) {} did not work because CCLocation2d was not Identifiable. I always wanted to build a class that held the PinLocation and Title, I inherited from Identifiable and it works. FYI: I'll update the sample app in GitHub with my changes, if anybody wished to see it.